# While working on a VGG-16 classification model. got an error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new in tf-python. i followed this tutorial - https://www.kaggle.com/loaiabdalslam/brain-tumor-mri-classification-vgg16#VGG-16 and at `In[34] ,having error "ValueError: None values not supported"`.

```
import time

start = time.time()

vgg16_history = vgg16.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=50,
    epochs=120,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=30,
)


end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code block which you have shared here. Can you share the complete code and data that you are using to reproduce your issue so that we can help you,Thanks!